# Unable to debug a map file due to Typed Polling schema in Biztalk

Tags: namespaces, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I have the below mentioned source schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling/EmailNotifications" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="TypedPolling">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="TypedPollingResultSet0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="TypedPollingResultSet0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="strPortName" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="LastRun_UTC" type="xs:dateTime" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The destination schema is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
<xs:schema xmlns="http://_024_EmailNotifications_Schemas.BizTalkDTADBExtractMod" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://_024_EmailNotifications_Schemas.BizTalkDTADBExtractMod" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Notification">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="strPortName" type="xs:string" /> 
              <xs:element name="LastRun_UTC" type="xs:string" /> 
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I have a map as shown below[image]

The input file for the map is

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/aggschema">
<InputMessagePart_0>
    <ns1:EmailNotifications xmlns:ns1="http://024_EmailNotifications_Schemas.XMLConfig">
        <App>
            <Name>App1</Name>
            <Port>Port1</Port>
            <Email>email</Email>
        </App>
        <App>
            <Name>App2</Name>
            <Port>Port2</Port>
            <Email>Email2</Email>
        </App>
        <App>
            <Name>App3</Name>
            <Port>Port3</Port>
            <Email>Email3</Email>
        </App>
        <App>
            <Name>App4</Name>
            <Port />
            <Email>Email4</Email>
        </App>
    </ns1:EmailNotifications>
</InputMessagePart_0>
<InputMessagePart_1>
    <ns2:TypedPolling xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling/EmailNotifications">
        <TypedPollingResultSet0>
            <TypedPollingResultSet0>
                <strPortName>Port1</strPortName>
                <LastRun_UTC>2016-01-29T10:20:10.083Z</LastRun_UTC>
            </TypedPollingResultSet0>
            <TypedPollingResultSet0>
                <strPortName>Port2</strPortName>
                <LastRun_UTC>2016-01-29T11:37:38.82Z</LastRun_UTC>
            </TypedPollingResultSet0>
            <TypedPollingResultSet0>
                <strPortName>Port3</strPortName>
                <LastRun_UTC>2016-01-29T11:37:39.353Z</LastRun_UTC>
            </TypedPollingResultSet0>
        </TypedPollingResultSet0>
    </ns2:TypedPolling>
</InputMessagePart_1>
</ns0:Root>
```

When I try to run the debug option in the map, I get this error which is preventing me from debugging the map, and I don't have a clue how to fix it. Appreciate any help I can get

> E:\temp\EmailNotifications\InputInternal.xml: error btm1044: Input validation error: The element 'TypedPolling' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling/EmailNotifications' has invalid child element 'TypedPollingResultSet0' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling/EmailNotifications'. List of possible elements expected: 'TypedPollingResultSet0'.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not specify the maxOccurs, it defaults to 1. Try setting the nested <TypedPollingResultSet0> element's maxOccurs to unbounded:

```
    <xs:element name="TypedPollingResultSet0">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="TypedPollingResultSet0">
```

Comment: Thanks Gruff. I tried your suggestion, but still I end up with the same error

Comment: @Deepak What is the Element FormDefault set to on the TypedPolling schema? Try setting it to `Qualified` if it is not.

Comment: Applying the 'qualified' attribute, I was able to validate the schema instance, but when I try it on the map, it gives me the same error as before.

Comment: I opened up the input xml file in visual studio and the screen shows a wiggly line below the Second "TypedPollingResultSet0" in the second record.
looks like the code is getting confused because of the second record "TypedPollingRecordSet0". Wish I could append the image on my comments

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what corrected my issue.
I changed the name space from ..../EmailNotifications to ..../EmailNotification
That resolved the wiggly line issue in the input xml file in the visual studio.

Then I regenerated the schema file from the input file and viola the issue got resolved.

Thanks Gruff for the help